# Jobs support link still leads to MSE instead of MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, product-support

A recent question on MSE pointed out in the comments that the [Jobs support page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) link tells them to discuss bugs or feedback on MSE instead of on MSO.

[image: Link goes to MSE instead of MSO]

This switch from MSE to MSO is a pretty recent change so it's probably simply an oversight.

Can we please have the link direct users to MSO instead of MSE?

Comment: working to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed. Thanks for the bug report!